# Find "ul" element with Selenium using Python by X_PATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

[The code I want to extract the "ul" element from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBClB.png)

[image]

[After trying suggestion, I want to get "title" in the follwing "li" tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJEn7.png)

I'm trying to extract the following "ul" element from a webpage using selenium. Using Python, I can't figure out what the X_PATH should be, I've tried everything I could think of. Also tried the css_selection. I'm getting back nothing.

I want to iterate over the "li" elements within that specific "ul" element. If anybody could help it would be appreciated, I've literally tried everything I can think/search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//ul[@aria-label='Chat content']/li[1]/div[1]/div[1]
```

To me it looks like you could just grab the ul by it's aria label and then select the first li from there. You could also just inspect the element and copy the xpath from the developers console.

It also seems to be in an iframe.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@class='embedded-electron-webview embedded-page-content']")))
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I've tried using aria-label, it returned an empty list. I want to get the ul because I then want to loop over all the li and pull information from each one, not only the first one. I've also tried copy xpath in dev console, it also returns an empty list. Which is why I'm so confused

Comment: It's also in an iframe switch to it first.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. Just something to keep in mind for anyone else looking into this: You have to use `driver.switch_to.default_content()` to switch out of the iframe if you wish to run code of the other elements after

Answer (score 0):

Check is that element are inside some iFrame, maybe is for that, if that dont work install selenium extension in your browser and try to recreat the flow, you will receive all xpath, is a way that I use when nothing is working to me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).